# Postgresql - Pivot with Crosstab or alternative?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to pivot this and have the following result:

```
  Table_name        Column_name      Values         ddmf_etl_id
"PROFITCENTERID"    "CO_AREA"       "DE02"           16807487
"PROFITCENTERID"    "PROFIT_CTR"    "0000001119"     16807487
"PROFITCENTERID"    "CO_AREA"       "DE02"           16807488
"PROFITCENTERID"    "PROFIT_CTR"    "0000001120"     16807488
```

Unfortunately I have failed to do this with the following select as CROSSTAB has a limited number (3) of arguments:

```
SELECT  'PROFITCENTERID' AS table_name,t.*
FROM   

crosstab(

        'SELECT unnest(''{CO_AREA,PROFIT_CTR}''::text[]) AS col
             , row_number() OVER ()
             , unnest(ARRAY[CO_AREA::text,PROFIT_CTR::text]) AS val
        FROM   "1".PROFITCENTER_PROFITCENTERID'

   ) t (column_name text,  values text);
```

Result of the select statement (wrong) :

[image]

Are there other alternatives to Crosstab in Postgresql?  Or maybe is it possible to do this with Crosstab?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What about an alternative that returns the "transposed" rows as a single JSON value? Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest()` to double each row and select appropriate values:

```
select
    'profitcenterid' as table_name,
    unnest(array['co_area', 'profit_ctr']) as column_name,
    unnest(array[co_area, profit_ctr]) as value,
    ddmf_etl_id as ddmf_etl_id
from profitcenter_profitcenterid

   table_name   | column_name |   value    | ddmf_etl_id 
----------------+-------------+------------+-------------
 profitcenterid | co_area     | de02       |    16807487
 profitcenterid | profit_ctr  | 0000001119 |    16807487
 profitcenterid | co_area     | de02       |    16807488
 profitcenterid | profit_ctr  | 0000001120 |    16807488
(4 rows)
```

[Live demo in rextester.](https://rextester.com/RMVDL41944)

However, this is not much help to get the expected json result. You want to get arbitrary key names, so there is no way to automatically generate the objects based on a subquery result. They can be created with the primitive `jsonb_build_object()`:

```
select to_jsonb(s)
from (
    select
        'profitcenterid' as table_name,
        17 as type,
        '' as value,
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'co_area', 'value', co_area, 'type', 0, 'children', '[]'::jsonb),
            jsonb_build_object('name', 'profit_ctr', 'value', profit_ctr, 'type', 0, 'children', '[]'::jsonb)
        ) as children
    from profitcenter_profitcenterid
    ) s
```

[Example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/SUGC95967)

As a side note, the expected structure seems unnecessarily complex, simplicity is a virtue.

Comment: @pyme - The problem is that the expected output is not a valid json, use [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate it. Also, please deliver your query and the expected output in text format, e.g. in [rextester.](https://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)

Comment: The jsonb concatenate operator `||` [exists.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) See also [Merging JSONB values in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42944888/1995738) for a recursive merge.

Comment: You have a few issues, there is no place to discuss them here. Ask a new question.